# Avocado plant at home

Tags: houseplants, avocado

I have an avocado, growing at home for about 2 years now. The plant is in a pot with a top diameter about 25 cm and it started out very good. Now it is about 40 cm high and it has been growing big green leaves, but recently it is growing yellow leaves. Even the baby leaves start out yellow.
I water the plant regularly so I doubt that watering is an issue.

What I am thinking is that it needs nutrition.
Any suggestion?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you ever added fertilizer and have you ever reported it? A photo would also be a good idea.

Comment: No, I haven't added fertilizer and no soil change.

Answer (score 1):

There are various kinds of avocado trees. The South American varieties are very dwarf trees. The Tropical African avocado tree can grow quite tall trees. One thing that struck me on your pic is that there is no way the avocado tree does not wither in this small pot. You need a much bigger pot for the tree to grow.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes, someone is hungry here.
As a first step I recommend you get some generic plant fertilizer, ideally a liquid one for now and start fertilizing as prescribed on the container. You should see a significant improvement within just a few weeks. I suggest liquid because it’s easier to apply and somewhat quicker than the slower-release granules. You can of course switch to other kinds once you have taken care of the immediate lack of minerals.

Caveat: Do not try to make up for non-fertilizing by being “extra generous”. You would risk hurting your plant and ultimately do more harm than good.

If you see no improvement, please post another question and consider repotting - if you carefully pull at the stem and a while root ball pops out, your plant is root bound this needs also human intervention.

Comment: Thanks Stephie. I will try fertilizing.

Comment: By the way, can you recommend any home-made fertilizer?

Comment: Honestly, if you don’t know what you are doing and have a plant that’s already showing distress, I wouldn’t experiment with homemade stuff. Most would need quite a bit of fermenting etc. anyway. I usually use a combination of compost and mulching techniques outside and commercial products indoors and for container plants.

Comment: I agree with @Stephie, a general purpose fertiliser removes the need to find out exactly what is missing. I use an encapsulated (called slow-release)  fertiliser.